# Pyarrow: read stream into pandas dataframe high memory consumption

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, pyarrow, feather

I would like to to first write a stream into an arrow file and then later read it back into a pandas dataframe, with as little memory overhead as posible.

Writing data in batches works perfectly fine:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
import random

data = [pa.array([random.randint(0, 1000)]), pa.array(['B']), pa.array(['C'])]
columns = ['A','B','C']
batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_arrays(data, columns)

with pa.OSFile('test.arrow', 'wb') as f:
    with pa.RecordBatchStreamWriter(f, batch.schema) as writer:
        for i in range(1000 * 1000):
            data = [pa.array([random.randint(0, 1000)]), pa.array(['B']), pa.array(['C'])]
            batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_arrays(data, columns)
            writer.write_batch(batch)
```

Writing 1 million rows as above is fast and uses about 40MB memory during the entire write. This is perfectly fine.

However reading back is not fine since the memory consumption goes up to 2GB, before producing the final dataframe which is about 118MB.

I tried this:

```
with pa.input_stream('test.arrow') as f:
    reader = pa.BufferReader(f.read())
    table = pa.ipc.open_stream(reader).read_all()
    df1 = table.to_pandas(split_blocks=True, self_destruct=True)
```

and this, with the same memory overhead:

```
with open('test.arrow', 'rb') as f:
   df1 = pa.ipc.open_stream(f).read_pandas()
```

Dataframe size:

```
print(df1.info(memory_usage='deep'))

Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count    Dtype
---  ------  --------------    -----
 0   A       1000000 non-null  int64
 1   B       1000000 non-null  object
 2   C       1000000 non-null  object
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 118.3 MB
None
```

What I would need is either to fix the memory usage with pyarrow or a suggestion which other format I could use to write data into incrementally, then read all of it into a pandas dataframe and without too much memory overhead.

Comment: How are you measuring RAM usage?  By default pyarrow will use jemalloc (Linux) or mimalloc (Windows).  Both will overallocate more than they need but it's not really "in use".  The memory is often free for the OS to reclaim if neccesary (e.g. marked with `POSIX_MADV_DONTNEED` and other tricks).  Can you try running your test with the system allocator?  (`pa.set_memory_pool(pa.system_memory_pool())`) or using `pa.total_allocated_bytes()` to measure memory usage?

Comment: In general, if your final dataframe in Pandas is ~120MB I wouldn't expect to see much more than 2x that in use.  2GB seems overly high.

Comment: Note that you are having many RecordBatches each of a single row. That might give a lot of overhead, since those RecordBatches are first all created before converting them to a single Table.

Comment: I think @joris is right.  I see much less memory used if I switch to 1000 batches of 1000 rows instead of 1000000 batches of 1 row.  Also, the performance is much better too.

Comment: @joris that was it! I tried it with batches of 1000 rows and the memory usage barely goes up to 50MB. If you want to post it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Pace I was using the windows task manager to measure memory use. If i print pa.total_allocated_bytes() at the end of the script it gives me 8MB but this is after the dataframe has been created. I suppose I could execute it in a different thread to get the memory use during dataframe creation but that's a bit much work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is using many RecordBatches each of a single row. Such a RecordBatch has some overhead in addition to just the data (the schema, potential padding/alignment), and thus is not efficient for storing only a single row.

When reading the file with `read_all()` or `read_pandas()`, it first creates all those RecordBatches before converting them to a single Table. And then the overhead adds up, and this is what you are seeing.

The recommended size for a RecordBatch is of course dependent on the exact use case, but a typical size is 64k to 1M rows.

---

To see the effect of the padding to 64 bytes per array (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html#buffer-alignment-and-padding), let's check the total allocated bytes vs the actual bytes represented by the RecordBatch:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
 
batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_arrays(
    [pa.array([1]), pa.array(['B']), pa.array(['C'])],
    ['A','B','C']
)

# The size of the data stored in the RecordBatch
# 8 for the integer (int64), 9 for each string array (8 for the len-2 offset array (int32), 1 for the single string byte)
>>> batch.nbytes
26

# The size of the data actually being allocated by Arrow
# (5*64 for 5 buffers padded to 64 bytes)
>>> pa.total_allocated_bytes()
320
```

So you can see that just this padding already gives a big overhead for a tiny RecordBatch

Comment: Indeed this was the issue. Thanks a lot Joris